# How can I get text to wrap around inside a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```html
<div style="word-wrap: normal; width: 20rem; max-width: 30rem; border: 1px solid red;">
  already, always, very - a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).
</div>
```

What I would like is for the text to wrap itself around inside if the `<div>`. However it overflows and does not do any wrap around at all.

Is there a way I can make it wrap around instead of flowing out of the right side of the `<div>` ?

Comment: It does not flow outside of the div for me atleast - https://jsfiddle.net/fgxjbv7a/

Comment: this works in latest chrome, which browser and version are you using?

Comment: works in latest Firefox as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is not overflowing, you can see it with a background. 
You can make it more regular by adding

```
text-align: justify; text-align-last: left
```

```html
<div style="word-wrap: normal; width: 20rem; max-width: 30rem; background: #cacaca">
      already, always, very - a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).
    </div>


<div style="word-wrap: normal; width: 20rem; max-width: 30rem; text-align: justify; text-align-last: left">
      already, always, very - a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want this?

```html
<div style="word-wrap: normal; width: 15rem; max-width: 30rem; float: left; padding-right: 1rem;">
  already, always, very - a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).
</div>
<div style="word-wrap: normal; width: 15rem; max-width: 30rem; float: left;">
  already, always, very - a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).
</div>
```